# directx 9 meshes overlap c++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, directx

ok when i load three meshes and render them one of them goes over all of them. is there way to control which mesh would go in the front and which mesh would go in the back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you have Z buffering turned on and the transformed triangles of that covering mesh simply end up closer to the camera, or you've set up the device to ignore Z buffering, and the appearance depends on the order in which you drew them.  In either case, it sounds like you want to have Z buffering turned off, and then you can draw them in exactly the order you want.

I think Z buffering starts out as disabled, unless you enable it.  You can find more info here for DirectX 9:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219616(v=VS.85).aspx